# Conditions for the existence of a minimal non-empty set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,1]}$ be a family of sets of real numbers, parametrized by a real number $t$. It is given that $X_0 = \mathbb{R}$ and $X_1=\emptyset$ and the family is weakly-decreasing, i.e.:

$$
t > s \implies X_t\subseteq X_s.
$$

In some cases, there exists a maximal $t\in [0,1]$ for which $z_t$ is non-empty. For example, if $X_t = [t,1-t]$, it is nonempty iff $t\leq 1/2$, so the maximal $t$ is $1/2$.
However, in other cases there is no such maximal $t$. For example, if $X_t = (t,1-t)$, it is nonempty iff $t< 1/2$.

My question is: what conditions on the family $X_t$ guarantee that there exists a maximal $t\in [0,1]$ for which $X_t\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: I doubt that the sort of condition you want exists. Hmm, assuming there exists $t$ such that $X_t$ is a nonempty finite set is enough. I don't see what continuity could have to do with it - if $f(t)=1/2-t$ there is _no_ maximal $t$ with $f(t)\ne0$.

Comment: Having a maximal $t_M$ with $X_{t_M}\ne \emptyset$ would actually require a sort of "discontinuity" in that it jumps from $\|X_{t_M}\| \ge 1$ to $\|X_t\| = 0$ for all $t>t_M$. A continuous function $f$ with $f(1) = 0$ will likewise not have a maximum $t_M$ with $f(t_M) \ne 0$. Instead it will have a *minimum* $t_m$ such that $f(t) = 0$ for all $t \ge t_m$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Maybe it is sufficient that $X_t$ is closed for every $t$? See the example I added.

Comment: Of course being closed doesn't do it. Say $X_t=[0,1]$ for $0\le t<1$, $X_1=\emptyset$.